# Don't know where lever is to open top latch on steel cellar door

Tags: doors, basement, lock

I recently took over my recently passed Grandmother's house and she has a furnace in the cellar. Of course, the furnace went out, so I need access to the cellar in order to fix it. I moved from out of the city and have no idea about anything that has to do with cellars. Also, the area I am in is very cold and snowy, so I have to shovel through 5 feet of snow to access the door. I have cleared the snow off of the door, but there is still snow around it. There is a steel rod that I can see at the top of the door preventing me from opening it. I have no idea where the lever to release this rod is. It would take hours to clear the snow from all sides of the door, so I'm hoping someone on here might be able to help me locate the lever. I thought it would be obvious but I'm having difficulties. The cellar is steel, it is red, but other than that I have no specifications on it. Any suggestions on where to look for the lever?

Comment: It may be a cane bolt that only needs to be turned to get it to fall out of its release detents

Comment: A picture would really raise your odds of the right answer here. Your ONLY access to the cellar is via the outside bulkhead? There's not a trapdoor hiding under a rug or in a closet? Most bulkheads (the steel cellar door to outside) have a handle near the lower portion of the door, on the midline. If this is the ONLY access to the cellar, you may be looking for a lock. If there is internal access (even if you haven't found it yet) the exterior door may be locked from the inside, and need to be opened from the inside. Go looking inside.

Comment: Agree w/ @Ecnerwal. Most bulkhead doors are secured from within.